# Tool Tips in gmplot

Tags: python

I'm using gmplot python package to plot lat & long on google maps. I want to add some comments which will display on the location.

Can I do this with gmplot?

if not suggest me python packages which supports this on google maps.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and any research you've done already. It would also be helpful to be more specific about what you want to achieve - i.e. labels vs popups etc

Comment: @RoperMaps I want labels on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this problem. You can create hover text using the marker feature of gmplot. It is the "title" feature.

```
gmap = 
gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(center_lat=webb_lat,center_lng=webb_log,zoom=12)
gmap.coloricon = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/%s/"
for i, row in nobids.iterrows():
  gmap.marker(row['latitude'], row['longitude'],title=row['Merchant_Name']+"[No bid]")
```